# echo user information on a product not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, codeigniter-3

I have been trying to echo user information on a product but its not working. I used to try it with this join function in my model :

```
 public function getdata()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->join('products','products.user_id = users.user_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
           return $query->result_array();
        }
    }
```

It didn't work properly because it echoed for example all the usernames from the database when I tried to echo a username that belongs to the same user_id.

Now I tried to do it like this:

This is my Controller function (AlleCadeausController):

```
public function index()
{
     /** Laad de models **/
    $this->load->model('Product_model');
    $selectProducts = $this->Product_model->selectProducts();   
    foreach ($selectProducts as $key => $product) 
    {
        # first name
        $user = $this->Product_model->get_user_name($product['user_id']);
        #append both NEW VALUES to same array
        $data[$key]['voornaam'] = $user[0]['voornaam'];
    }
     /** Make $data **/
    $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->selectProducts();
     /** Laad de allecadeaus view en geef $data mee **/
    $this->load->view('allecadeaus', $data);
}
```

My model functions in my Prduct_model.php file:

```
public function selectProducts()
{
    $query= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM products");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}

function get_user_name($name)
{
    $query= $this->db->query("SELECT voornaam FROM users WHERE user_id = $name ");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

And this is how I tried to echo the user information in the product foreach loop in the view:

```
<?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>  
    <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product["product_id"]; ?>"> 
        <div class="main-products">
            <img id="cadeaufoto" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product["product_foto_thumb"]; ?>">
            <div class="product_naam"><?php echo $product["product_naam"]; ?></div>
            <div class="ophaal_plaats"><?php  echo $product["ophaal_plaats"]; ?></div>
        </div>    
    </a>         
    <div class="aangeboden_door">     
        <p>
            <tr>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'User/userdetails/'.$product['user_id'];?>">
                <td><?php echo $product['voornaam'];?></td>
            </tr> 
        </p>  
    </div> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

at this line :

> `<td><?php echo $product['voornaam'];?></td>`I try to echo the first
>   name of the user of the product but its not working.
>       The PHP error that I'm receiving is: `undefined index: voornaam , line: 55` which is this line: `<td><?php echo
>   $product['voornaam'];?></td>`

Database information of both tables products and users:

```
Table 1 : products:

product_id
product_naam
product_beschrijving
user_id
ophaal_plaats
product_foto
product_foto_thumb
date_created
date_updated
category_id

table 2 : users:

user_id
email
voornaam
achternaam
beschrijving
profiel_foto
```

Comment: Your query is returning all usernames because you need to add which user id you are after. So you need something like $this->db->where(users.user_id,$user_id); but you have to determine where you get the value for $user_id from.

Comment: Tip: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Comment: Whats up with that? I'm loading the model correctly right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the active records instead of create multiple function:

Your controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = array();
    $this->load->model('product_model');
    $data['products'] = $this->product_model->selectProducts();
    $this->load->view('allecadeaus', $data);
}
```

Your view:

Your view:

```
<?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>  
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product["product_id"]; ?>"> 
  <div class="main-products">
    <img id="cadeaufoto" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product["product_foto_thumb"]; ?>">
    <div class="product_naam"><?php echo $product["product_naam"]; ?></div>
    <div class="ophaal_plaats"><?php  echo $product["ophaal_plaats"]; ?></div>
  </div>    
</a>         
<div class="aangeboden_door">     
  <p>
    <tr>
      <?php 
          //Here is the active record query which is getting the 'voorname' and other data
          $userarray = $this->db->get_where('users', array('user_id'=>$product["user_id"]))->row_array(); 
          // you can print_r($userarray); for see the array you get
      ?>
      <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'User/userdetails/'.$product['user_id'];?>">
      <td><?php echo $userarray['voornaam'];?></td>
    </tr> 
  </p>  
</div> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Accept if u like